# Mailchimp API status 200 for members who are already subscribed

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

The following code is working and subscribing new members successfully. However, the status returns 200 even if the email address is already subscribed. I have checked that $member_id is hashing correctly, and despite identical values it still returns 200.

```
$result = array(
    'status' => sync_mailchimp($data)
);

var_dump($result) // 200

function sync_mailchimp($data) {

    // Setup our Mailchimp info
    $api_key = 'xxxxx';
    $list_id = 'ab8abde5bb';

    $member_id  = md5(strtolower($data['email'])); // lowercase hash of the email
    $datacenter = 'us16';
    $url = 'https://' . $datacenter . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $list_id . '/members/' . $member_id;

    $json = json_encode([
        'email_address' => $data['email'],
        'status'        => $data['status']
    ]);

    // Send via curl
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:' . $api_key);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);                                                                                                                 

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $httpcode;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also having the same issue while using a similar snippet.

Reading the MailChimp API 3.0 docs relating to [managing subscribers](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/manage-subscribers-with-the-mailchimp-api/) (specifically the section **Subscribe an Address**), it was clear that this method was not the correct way to add a new subscriber.

The request type needs to be a POST

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');`

and must be sent to the endpoint

`https://<data_center>.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/<list_id>/members/`

The request body containing the JSON is identical.

The response code will be `200` when an email address is added to the list successfully, and `400` when the email address already exists on the list.

*Note that this method will not work for updating an existing subscriber – to do that, the request type must be `PATCH`, and you must use the original endpoint ending with the hashed email address.*